# the CRUD methods not created in grails 2.3.4 controller

Tags: grails

In **Grails 2.3.4**, in creating the controller why it does not create the CURD methods ,although  i put in the domain :

```
 static scaffold = true
```

the contoller only got 1 method called :

```
index
```

I'm wondering where are the rest of the methods show , create , ...etc

Answer (score 1):

When you use `static scaffold = true` you're using dynamic scaffolding. This means that the controller and GSPs are created in-memory for you. When you use the generate-* scripts, e.g. `generate-all`, `generate-controller`, and `generate-views` you're using static scaffolding. These scripts create real files that you can edit. But if you don't edit anything, the net result is the same.

Dynamic scaffolding is good for getting started, for demos, and sometimes for simple admin UIs. But you'll find static scaffolding is better in general since the generated code (either dynamic in-memory or static) is only a decent starting point and you'll need to do some customization.

This is described in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html

Comment: Hi i followed the steps mentioned in the link you sent , but i still cant see the methods or views, in the views folder there is a folder with my controller's name but it's empty ..